# Create new document based on content type

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, csom

How can you programticly create a new document in a document library using CSOM? The new document should be from the document template.

```
            ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://localhost");
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("CustomDocumentLibrary")

            var folder = list.RootFolder;
            clientContext.Load(folder);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            var cType = clientContext.LoadQuery(list.ContentTypes.Where(x => x.Name == "CustomContentType"));
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            ContentType targetDocumentSetContentType = cType.FirstOrDefault();
            string contentTypeId = targetDocumentSetContentType.Id.ToString();

            // Change to load the document template from Content Type
            FileCreationInformation fileCreateInfo = new FileCreationInformation();
            byte[] fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\files\template.docx");     
            fileCreateInfo.Content = fileContent;

            fileCreateInfo.Url = folder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/New_File.docx";

            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = folder.Files.Add(fileCreateInfo);
            clientContext.Load(list);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();


            ListItem newItem = uploadFile.ListItemAllFields;
            newItem["Title"] = "Title";
            newItem["ContentTypeId"] = contentTypeId;
            newItem.Update();
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Ok, so you've posted some code. What error are your experiencing? Please clarify your *real* problem.